# How to Golang loop in html with http/template and net/http?

Tags: go

I am trying to handle data and then send it into html to be displayed in a specific field.

No expected output into {{.name}}. Works fine with {{.}}. No known structural wrongdoing.

**Golang code**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/context"
)

var tpl *template.Template

func main() {

    tpl, _ = template.ParseGlob("*.html")
    http.HandleFunc("/test", testHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", context.ClearHandler(http.DefaultServeMux))

}

type Data struct {
    allData []string
}


func testHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    data := Data{allData: []string{"Add new", "jeff", "ffeej"}}

    tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "test.html", data)
}
```

**HTML code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
    <body>
 
        <section>
            {{range .allData}}
                {{.}}
            {{end}}
        </section>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

How does one get the data out of the handler into the html in a specific wanted field?

What am I missing? I am still learning golang.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `allData` => `AllData`. In both the struct and the template. Lowercase names are **unexported** (not accessible outside of their own package), uppercase names are **exported**.

Comment: *"I am still learning golang."* -- You should never ignore errors. The `tpl.ExecuteTemplate` method returns an error, make sure to check it to see details about what went wrong, if anything.